# Set urlText in jQuery drop and drop image upload plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jquery plugin http://git.razko.nl/InlineAttachment/ for drag and drop image uploads.

In my .js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('textarea').inlineattachment({
      uploadUrl: 'upload_attachment.php',
      urlText: "testing" //this is not working.
    });
  });
});
```

Am I using this wrongly? Will appreciate help!

Comment: what error did you get??

Comment: No error message. I'm expecting `When a file has successfully been uploaded the last inserted text will be replaced by the urlText, the {filename} tag will be replaced by the filename that has been returned by the server`, that the last inserted text will be replaced by "testing", as in the docs, however, nothing changed.

Comment: Is the `testing` returned from the server or is it hardcoded?

Comment: hardcoded just to see if it works.

Comment: I tried `"![file]({filename})"` but it didn't work.

Comment: have you tried this way : `"![file](testing)"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('textarea').inlineattachment({
      uploadUrl: 'upload_attachment.php',
      urlText: 'testing'
   });
});
```